# Getting 502 response and 'has been blocked by CORS policy' running a simple fetch request to my lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, authorization, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless

Building a serverless web app on AWS with the serverless framework, I get a CORS error with a 502 response code authenticating against an AWS Cognito user pool

```
GET https://URL.amazonaws.com/dev/asset/ID-1178 502
index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://URL.amazonaws.com/dev/asset/PO-TIENDA1178' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.js:109 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

An almost identical request works for another function.

And here are both ajax requests sent from the frontend:

```js
// working just fine

        async function getAllAssets() {
            const getAssetsUrl = _config.api.invokeUrl + "/assets"
            const response = await fetch(getAssetsUrl, {
                headers: { 
                    Authorization: authToken
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true
            })
        }

// not working, throwing the error described above

        async function getOneAsset() {
            const getAssetsUrl = _config.api.invokeUrl + "/asset/" + "ID-1178"
            const response = await fetch(getAssetsUrl, {
                headers: { 
                    Authorization: authToken
                },
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true
            })
        }
```

I run both functions onDocReady in the same window.

Here are the definitions in serverless.yaml:

```
  # WORKS 
  getAssets:
    name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-get-assets
    handler: handler.getAssets
    role: InventoryLambdaRole
    events:
      - http:
          path: /assets
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:HARDCODED:ARN

  # doesn't work

  getAsset:
    name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-get-asset
    handler: handler.getAsset
    role: InventoryLambdaRole
    events:
      - http:
          path: /asset/{assetId}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:HARDCODED:ARN
```

And here goes my function implementations in the `handler.js`:

```js
// get all assets works fine:

module.exports.getAssets = function(event, context, callback) {
  const params = {
    TableName : 'Assets',
    Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
  }

  const request = documentClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err)
    } else {
      const itemCount = data.Count
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          itemCount: itemCount,
          assets: data
        }),
      }
      callback(null, response);
    }
  })
}

// get one asset doesn't work:
module.exports.getAsset = function(event, context, callback) {
  const params = {
    TableName : 'Assets',
    Key: {
      AssetId: event.pathParameters.assetId // also tried to just hardcode it like this: 'ID-1178' 
    }
  }

  const request = documentClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err)
    } else {
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          asset: data
        }),
      }
      callback(null, response);
    }
  })
```

Although it's a CORS error, as you can see the origin headers are provided, and I found that in combination with the 502 status it might be something before the CORS, e.g. a problem in the function or with authorization. However, I can't see any problems with them so far.

The serverless function itself works as well when invoke it locally:
`npm run sls -- invoke local --function getAsset -p test.json`

Do you have any ideas what could be the issue or how to debug it?

Comment: do you have IAM permission to dynamodb:GetItem?

Comment: f*ck, you are so right, my thought was, that if I can query them all then there should be everything clear with the permissions. But yeah, there it is, the                     - `dynamodb:PutItem` and `dynamodb:Scan` are present but not the GetItem. The whole confusion rabbit hole starts with the "wrong" CORS message in the browser or just the 'unauthorized' messages in the AWS console. Would there have been a place (logs, debug requests, whatever?) where I could have gotten a more precise message of what is wrong?

Comment: @LostJon feel free to submit the answer ;)

Comment: glad to help...IAM is a tough one and it seems that a 403 would have been a better response...but when working w/ API gateway and malformed responses, the actual issue gets a bit hazy

Comment: FYI, to debug, i would have tried to invoke the lambda function the same way as your service would...normally the response from lambda directly is a bit better than the proxied response.

Comment: @LostJon yeah, you are very right. I remember running the 'Test' in the console but I seem to have ignored the actual error which clearly states the issue: `2019-12-04T09:25:13.825Z f48c5178-4ffe-498f-8a00-ab2230219802 INFO Error { AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::0989304820438:assumed-role/serverless-dev-eu-west-1-inventoryLambda/serverless-inventory-tool-dev-get-asset is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:930284290348:table/Assets` Thank you very much 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be as simple as having `dynamodb:GetItem`. This is a different permission than what listing all (ie query or scan) would be